# Whats the difference between 'for x in list:' and 'for x in list[:]:'

Tags: python, list

I'm following a pygame book and both of these notations appear:

```
for x in xs:
    # do something with x

for x in xs[:]:
    # do something with x
```

Do they have the same meaning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`xs[:]` copies the list.

- `for x in xs` -- Iterate over the list `xs` as-is.
- `for x in xs[:]` -- Iterate over the a copy of list `xs`.

One of the reasons why you'd want to "iterate over a copy"
is for in-place modification of the original list. The other common reason for "copying" is atomicity of the data you're dealing with. (*i.e: another thread/process modifies the list or data structure as you're reading it*).

**Note:** Be aware however that in-place modification can still modify indices of the original list you have copied.

**Example:**

```
# Remove even numbers from a list of integers.
xs = list(range(10))
for x in xs[:]:
    if x % 2 == 0:
        xs.remove(x)
```

Comment: This is still kind of dangerous, isn't it? If you have to delete an element in the middle, and then at the very end, you could get an `IndexError` if I'm thinking this through correctly.

Comment: that's kind of the point though, you're iterating over a copy while modifying the original. Therefore you'll have indexes in the copy that are no longer in the original.

Comment: Well it still answers his question, so it's all good I'm sure :)

Comment: So I would use `for x in xs:` when I know need to read values or simply to modify each of them(i.e multiply each element by 2), and I would use `for x in xs[:]:` whenever I'm changing the size of the list by deleting/adding elements? Oh this makes sense because in my book it was used to remove enemies from a list whenever they move off screen. I can see why iterating over a loop while removing items would cause problems.

Comment: The example you had would work if you used `list.remove(x)` rather than `del x[i]`. A better example might be adding elements, rather than removing them: `for x in xs[:]: if x % 2: xs.append(x)` which adds an extra copy of all the odd elements. Without the slice, you'd loop forever.

Answer (score 3):

They have mostly the same meaning, *except* when you're modifying the list inside the body of the loop. The form `list[:]` explicitly makes a copy of the list before iterating over it, leaving you free to modify the original list (such as by deleting items) during loop iteration. Removing items from a list while directly iterating over it is not recommended.

Comment: You might want to talk about what if `L` contains instances of a custom class, and I do `for x in L[:]: x.increment()`. The side-effects of such calls will be missed by the shallow copying

Comment: Well, that's not modifying *the list*, that's modifying some other object. Not quite the same thing.

Comment: Good explanation, completely understand now.